# What do the forward and backward propagation algorithms look like for convolutional neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

I've tried writing convolutional neural networks a few times and I always, always, always fail.

It would be really useful if someone could write out the forward and back propagation algorithms in pseudo code. The more detail the better. It would also be helpful if the size of arrays/matrix into a function could be stated.

I realise this isn't a typical stack exchange type question, and if it's too far from the norm then please feel free to downvote. I *think* this would be useful for many people interested I like this topic and it would be a good first check type question when someone looks up ConvNets. If the question isn't deleted and I ever figure it all out I will answer it myself!

Comment: +1 I think a pseudocode request is a perfectly reasonable use of this site and in compliance with our objectives and how we work.

Comment: Isn't this about how to write code for a convolutional neural network? If that is the case I think it would be off-topic here.

Comment: @MichaelChernick he's not asking for the code of a CNN. He's asking the psuedocode of the forward/backpropagation of a CNN. Which is basically asking how a certain algorithm works... seems on-topic, I think.

Comment: I'm glad the question has been well received! Now if I could only figure out the back propagation...